# Why would you use the using statement this way in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, using-statement

Refactoring some code again.  Seeing some of this in one of the ASP.NET pages:

```
using (TextBox txtBox = e.Row.Cells[1].FindControl("txtBox") as TextBox)
{
}
```

There is no need to dispose txtBox, because it's just a reference to an existing control.  And you don't want the control disposed at all.  I'm not even sure this isn't harmful - like it would appear to ask for the underlying control to be disposed inappropriately (although I have not yet seen any ill effects from it being used this way).

Comment: I think the using is not needed in there.

Comment: Looks like a rookie mistake on the original dev's part, not fully understanding what `using` does.

Comment: To quote Chris Griffin, "I don't think you need the usin...Whaaaaaaa!?"

Comment: "Wow, `using` isn't just for namespaces? I'm gonna **use** everything!"

Comment: @Davide Piras: I believe you are correct there. Looks like someone got excited by Using and is using it everywhere. The underlying object should not be being disposed of as there will still be references to it elsewhere in the app.

Comment: @BoltClock Of course, there are many legitimate (non-namespace) usings in this code - particularly with the database access.  I don't think it's in a lot of the forms, because this is the first time I think I've seen it.

Comment: I've seen lots of negative side-effects when I used `using` improperly with the `Image` or `Bitmap` class.

Comment: Get rid of the `using` statement, it's doing nothing but causing an eyesore...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TextBox` inherits its implementation of `IDisposable` from its [Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx) superclass. That implementation removes the component from its [site container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isite.aspx) if it has one.

So, doing that might have nefarious effects if the text box actually resides in a site container. Also, after calling `Dispose()` on an object, you should not use it again, no matter what (it's not in a usable state anymore).

I'd suggest you avoid that pattern with ASP.NET web controls.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong, it shouldnt be used like this.  I would imagine there are potential problems using this that wont show up immediately.  The textboxes dispose is called upon leaving the using statement but it wont be garbage collected immediately.  If it is collected then you will have problems later when you try to access that control.

Answer (score 4):

The `TextBox` instance could potentially be null if not found, so Dispose() is called a `NullReferenceException` would be thrown.

I've never seen that pattern in practice, but if you need to use it, it'd be worth handling any potential errors.

Comment: The specification for the `using` statement ensures that `Dispose()` won't be called if the value is `null`.

Comment: @zinglon Good point, and I think perhaps the original coder thought that putting the using would also mean that the inner code would only be called for non-NULL parameters, too, which is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

There should be no negative secondary effects, but it's not necessary either. If we did `using (x) { ... }` on everything that implements IDisposable in the CLR most C# code would be unreadable.

Comment: Since the obejct is in a (potentially) unusable state after calling Dispose there definately potential unwanted secondary effects.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, here the TextBox instance is accessible only to the context inside the brackets of using statement, maybe that was the main reason of using it.

Comment: Possibly a good use, I guess, but they could always have just put them in a scope with a naked {} scope.  There is at least one case in this form where they've put 8 usings (not 8 within one using) nested with brackets.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> Within the using block, **the object
>   is read-only** and cannot be modified
>   or reassigned.

So I guess you can only read the textbox properties, but not change them, inside the using block.

Comment: The properties definitely get changed, including .Text, .Visible and others.

Comment: All that means is you can't do `using (TextBox txtBox = ...) { txtBox = new TextBox(); }` The object reference is read-only, but the object itself is not necessarily immutable.